# Does this have a limit?

Tags: probability, limits

Does this have a limit as $n \to \infty$ : ${\alpha}^{2(-1)^{n + 1}n}{\beta}^{(-1)^{n}(2n+1)}$ and $0< \alpha, \beta < 1$.

Answer (score 2):

No it does not. Forget about the $ \alpha $ term for a moment - it is either $ \alpha^2 $ or $\alpha^{-2} $. For odd $ n $, $ \beta^{(-1)^n (2n+1)} = \left( \frac{1}{\beta} \right)^{2n+1} $. Since $\frac{1}{\beta} > 1 $, this diverges. So for odd $ n $ the series diverges. Similarly, for even $n$, it goes to 0.